# How can i send a webook to my django app and only execute it on logged in user

Tags: django

Hi i am new to coding and only been learning python and django for about a week. so sorry if this does not make sense.

i am trying to send a webhook(this is just a test then ill add json)
so that when i send to http://127.0.0.1:8000/webhook
i am using postmen desktop so i receive the webhooks.

it will execute my session code but the problem i have that in my app i have
already set up users db and when i sent the webhook it return none since no one seems to be logged in. i know i will have to add a code something like a token to specify each user but only want to test with one user first.

i get the error None or when i remove user authenticated then it says i can't send to anonymous user. is there a way i can send it to lets say a specific user or ID or let's say a token i save with the user.

```
@csrf_exempt
def webhook(request):
        #get current users keys        
        if  request.user.is_authenticated:
            user = request.user
            database = Bybitapidatas.objects.all().filter(user=user)
            for apikey in database:
                apikey = apikey.apikey
            for apisecret in database:
                apisecret = apisecret.apisecret

            session = HTTP(endpoint='https://api-testnet.bybit.com/', api_key=apikey, api_secret=apisecret,spot=True)

            print(session.place_active_order(
                symbol="BTCUSDT",
                side="Buy",
                type="MARKET",
                qty="20",
                timeInForce="GTC"
            ))
```

Comment: i am using the apikey , and apisecret that i get from the logged in user so without specifying the user i can't pull the data

Comment: `i know i will have to add a code something like a token to specify each user but only want to test with one user first.` If it is strictly for testing and if you don't want to use a token for now, you still need to identify/get a user to use. How about just getting the first user?

Comment: @BrianDestura yes that is what i am trying to do but like ive mentioned a bit new to this. so i am looking for a way to call a username from the database and then use its attached data for apikey and apisecret